# Как грамотно написать предложение в прайс-листе

Tags: лингвистика

Оплата за выполненные ремонтные работы /попутно,по пути, по ходу, но не дополнительные/ оплачивается не полностью как указано в прайс листе. А дополнительно к основному ремонту добавляется разница цен

Comment: Пардон, а "советское" слово прейскурант сейчас совсем забыто?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала нужно прояснить, какую мысль хочет выразить автор в договоре.

У меня получилось что-то вроде:

> Оплата за <дополнительно> выполненные ремонтные работы рассчитывается
>   исходя из разницы цен между *стоимостью основного ремонта и стоимостью
>   работ по прайс-листу.*

Часть предложения выделенная курсивом -- это не более, чем мои догадки, какая формула калькуляции используется. Особенно это критично для составления строгих юридических документов.

Тем не менее, в таком переформулированном виде ответ на вопрос топикстартера звучит следующим образом:

Вместо слова "дополнительно" в обороте "дополнительно выполненные работы" вполне уместно использовать слово "попутно":

> Оплата за <попутно> выполненные ремонтные работы рассчитывается исходя из ...

Альтернативный вариант указан в ответе @behemothus, мне тоже очень нравится:

> Оплата за сопутствующие ремонтные работы рассчитывается исходя из ...

Остальные слова не подходят, разве что можно употребить слово "походу" (обратите внимание, что его нужно писать слитно). Но оно имеет какой-то жаргонный оттенок.

Также обращаю внимание топикстартера на то, что "оплата оплачивается" -- это не очень удачный оборот ("масло масленное"), поэтому я убрал из переформулированного предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не понял. Трудно что-то советовать, не уловив смысл.

Но если говорить об одном слове, ***вспомогательные*** (работы) не подойдет? ***Сопутствующие***? ***Сопряженные***?

> А дополнительно к основному ремонту добавляется разница цен

**-????**
Вскипел мой разум возмущенный (С)

Answer (score -1):

Следует писать прайс-лист. Употребляем дефис.

Но в предложении есть и другие ошибки.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?